# ValueError:Tensor("inputs:0", shape=(None, 256, 256, 3), dtype=uint8)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I don't know how to solve this error i also tried converting it into float32

```
import cv2
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

CATEGORIES = ["gas", "break","stop"]

model = tf.keras.models.load_model("trained")


def prepare(filepath):
    IMG_SIZE = 256  # 50 in txt-based
    img_array = cv2.imread(filepath)
    new_array = cv2.resize(img_array, (IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE))
    arr=new_array.reshape(-1, IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 3)
    return arr

x=prepare('img.jpg')
x = tf.keras.utils.normalize(x, axis=1)
x = x.astype('float32') 
print(x.dtype)
prediction = model.predict([x])
print(prediction)  # will be a list in a list.
print(CATEGORIES[np.argmax(prediction[0])])
```

> float32
>   --------------------------------------------------------------------------- ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in 
>        11 x = x.astype('float32')
>        12 print(x.dtype)
>   ---> 13 prediction = model.predict([x])
>        14 print(prediction)  # will be a list in a list.
>        15 print(CATEGORIES[np.argmax(prediction[0])])
>
> ~\anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training.py
>   in predict(self, x, batch_size, verbose, steps, callbacks,
>   max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing)    1011
>   max_queue_size=max_queue_size,    1012         workers=workers,
>   -> 1013         use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing)    1014     1015   def reset_metrics(self):
>
> ~\anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_v2.py
>   in predict(self, model, x, batch_size, verbose, steps, callbacks,
>   max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, **kwargs)
>       496         model, ModeKeys.PREDICT, x=x, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=verbose,
>       497         steps=steps, callbacks=callbacks, max_queue_size=max_queue_size,
>   --> 498         workers=workers, use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing, **kwargs)
>       499 
>       500
>
> ~\anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_v2.py
>   in _model_iteration(self, model, mode, x, y, batch_size, verbose,
>   sample_weight, steps, callbacks, max_queue_size, workers,
>   use_multiprocessing, **kwargs)
>       473               mode=mode,
>       474               training_context=training_context,
>   --> 475               total_epochs=1)
>       476           cbks.make_logs(model, epoch_logs, result, mode)
>       477
>
> ~\anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_v2.py
>   in run_one_epoch(model, iterator, execution_function, dataset_size,
>   batch_size, strategy, steps_per_epoch, num_samples, mode,
>   training_context, total_epochs)
>       126         step=step, mode=mode, size=current_batch_size) as batch_logs:
>       127       try:
>   --> 128         batch_outs = execution_function(iterator)
>       129       except (StopIteration, errors.OutOfRangeError):
>       130         # TODO(kaftan): File bug about tf function and errors.OutOfRangeError?
>
> ~\anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_v2_utils.py
>   in execution_function(input_fn)
>        96     # `numpy` translates Tensors to values in Eager mode.
>        97     return nest.map_structure(_non_none_constant_value,
>   ---> 98                               distributed_function(input_fn))
>        99 
>       100   return execution_function
>
> ~\anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\def_function.py
>   in **call**(self, *args, **kwds)
>       566         xla_context.Exit()
>       567     else:
>   --> 568       result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
>       569 
>       570     if tracing_count == self._get_tracing_count():
>
> ~\anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\def_function.py
>   in _call(self, *args, **kwds)
>       613       # This is the first call of **call**, so we have to initialize.
>       614       initializers = []
>   --> 615       self._initialize(args, kwds, add_initializers_to=initializers)
>       616     finally:
>       617       # At this point we know that the initialization is complete (or less
>
> ~\anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\def_function.py
>   in _initialize(self, args, kwds, add_initializers_to)
>       495     self._concrete_stateful_fn = (
>       496         self._stateful_fn._get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected(
>
> ## pylint: disable=protected-access
>
> --> 497             *args, **kwds))
>       498 
>       499     def invalid_creator_scope(*unused_args, **unused_kwds):
>
> ~\anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\function.py
>   in _get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected(self, *args,
>   **kwargs)    2387       args, kwargs = None, None    2388     with self._lock:
>   -> 2389       graph_function, _, _ = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)    2390     return graph_function    2391
>
> ~\anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\function.py
>   in _maybe_define_function(self, args, kwargs)    2701     2702
>   self._function_cache.missed.add(call_context_key)
>   -> 2703       graph_function = self._create_graph_function(args, kwargs)    2704       self._function_cache.primary[cache_key] =
>   graph_function    2705       return graph_function, args, kwargs
>
> ~\anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\function.py
>   in _create_graph_function(self, args, kwargs,
>   override_flat_arg_shapes)    2591             arg_names=arg_names,
>   2592             override_flat_arg_shapes=override_flat_arg_shapes,
>   -> 2593             capture_by_value=self._capture_by_value),    2594         self._function_attributes,    2595         # Tell the ConcreteFunction
>   to clean up its graph once it goes out of
>
> ~\anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\framework\func_graph.py
>   in func_graph_from_py_func(name, python_func, args, kwargs, signature,
>   func_graph, autograph, autograph_options, add_control_dependencies,
>   arg_names, op_return_value, collections, capture_by_value,
>   override_flat_arg_shapes)
>       976                                           converted_func)
>       977 
>   --> 978       func_outputs = python_func(*func_args, **func_kwargs)
>       979 
>       980       # invariant: `func_outputs` contains only Tensors, CompositeTensors,
>
> ~\anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\def_function.py
>   in wrapped_fn(*args, **kwds)
>       437         # **wrapped** allows AutoGraph to swap in a converted function. We give
>       438         # the function a weak reference to itself to avoid a reference cycle.
>   --> 439         return weak_wrapped_fn().**wrapped**(*args, **kwds)
>       440     weak_wrapped_fn = weakref.ref(wrapped_fn)
>       441
>
> ~\anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_v2_utils.py
>   in distributed_function(input_iterator)
>        83     args = _prepare_feed_values(model, input_iterator, mode, strategy)
>        84     outputs = strategy.experimental_run_v2(
>   ---> 85         per_replica_function, args=args)
>        86     # Out of PerReplica outputs reduce or pick values to return.
>        87     all_outputs = dist_utils.unwrap_output_dict(
>
> ~\anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\distribute\distribute_lib.py
>   in experimental_run_v2(self, fn, args, kwargs)
>       761       fn = autograph.tf_convert(fn, ag_ctx.control_status_ctx(),
>       762                                 convert_by_default=False)
>   --> 763       return self._extended.call_for_each_replica(fn, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
>       764 
>       765   def reduce(self, reduce_op, value, axis):
>
> ~\anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\distribute\distribute_lib.py
>   in call_for_each_replica(self, fn, args, kwargs)    1817       kwargs
>   = {}    1818     with self._container_strategy().scope():
>   -> 1819       return self._call_for_each_replica(fn, args, kwargs)    1820     1821   def _call_for_each_replica(self, fn, args, kwargs):
>
> ~\anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\distribute\distribute_lib.py
>   in _call_for_each_replica(self, fn, args, kwargs)    2162
>   self._container_strategy(),    2163
>   replica_id_in_sync_group=constant_op.constant(0, dtypes.int32)):
>   -> 2164       return fn(*args, **kwargs)    2165     2166   def _reduce_to(self, reduce_op, value, destinations):
>
> ~\anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\autograph\impl\api.py
>   in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
>       290   def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
>       291     with ag_ctx.ControlStatusCtx(status=ag_ctx.Status.DISABLED):
>   --> 292       return func(*args, **kwargs)
>       293 
>       294   if inspect.isfunction(func) or inspect.ismethod(func):
>
> ~\anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_v2_utils.py
>   in _predict_on_batch(***failed resolving arguments***)
>       210       del y, sample_weights
>       211       # Note that the x and batch_index is already per-replica value.
>   --> 212       result = predict_on_batch(model, x)
>       213       if batch_index is None:
>       214         return result
>
> ~\anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_v2_utils.py
>   in predict_on_batch(model, x, standalone)
>       554 
>       555   with backend.eager_learning_phase_scope(0):
>   --> 556     return predict_on_batch_fn(inputs)  # pylint: disable=not-callable
>
> ~\anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\base_layer.py
>   in **call**(self, inputs, *args, **kwargs)
>       776                     outputs = base_layer_utils.mark_as_return(outputs, acd)
>       777                 else:
>   --> 778                   outputs = call_fn(cast_inputs, *args, **kwargs)
>       779 
>       780             except errors.OperatorNotAllowedInGraphError as e:
>
> ~\anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\sequential.py
>   in call(self, inputs, training, mask)
>       279         kwargs['training'] = training
>       280 
>   --> 281       outputs = layer(inputs, **kwargs)
>       282 
>       283       # `outputs` will be the inputs to the next layer.
>
> ~\anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\base_layer.py
>   in **call**(self, inputs, *args, **kwargs)
>       776                     outputs = base_layer_utils.mark_as_return(outputs, acd)
>       777                 else:
>   --> 778                   outputs = call_fn(cast_inputs, *args, **kwargs)
>       779 
>       780             except errors.OperatorNotAllowedInGraphError as e:
>
> ~\anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\saving\saved_model\utils.py
>   in return_outputs_and_add_losses(*args, **kwargs)
>        57     inputs = args[inputs_arg_index]
>        58     args = args[inputs_arg_index + 1:]
>   ---> 59     outputs, losses = fn(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
>        60     layer.add_loss(losses, inputs)
>        61     return outputs
>
> ~\anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\def_function.py
>   in **call**(self, *args, **kwds)
>       566         xla_context.Exit()
>       567     else:
>   --> 568       result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
>       569 
>       570     if tracing_count == self._get_tracing_count():
>
> ~\anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\def_function.py
>   in _call(self, *args, **kwds)
>       604       # In this case we have not created variables on the first call. So we can
>       605       # run the first trace but we should fail if variables are created.
>   --> 606       results = self._stateful_fn(*args, **kwds)
>       607       if self._created_variables:
>       608         raise ValueError("Creating variables on a non-first call to a function"
>
> ~\anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\function.py
>   in **call**(self, *args, **kwargs)    2360     """Calls a graph
>   function specialized to the inputs."""    2361     with self._lock:
>   -> 2362       graph_function, args, kwargs = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)    2363     return
>   graph_function._filtered_call(args, kwargs)  # pylint:
>   disable=protected-access    2364
>
> ~\anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\function.py
>   in _maybe_define_function(self, args, kwargs)    2701     2702
>   self._function_cache.missed.add(call_context_key)
>   -> 2703       graph_function = self._create_graph_function(args, kwargs)    2704       self._function_cache.primary[cache_key] =
>   graph_function    2705       return graph_function, args, kwargs
>
> ~\anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\function.py
>   in _create_graph_function(self, args, kwargs,
>   override_flat_arg_shapes)    2591             arg_names=arg_names,
>   2592             override_flat_arg_shapes=override_flat_arg_shapes,
>   -> 2593             capture_by_value=self._capture_by_value),    2594         self._function_attributes,    2595         # Tell the ConcreteFunction
>   to clean up its graph once it goes out of
>
> ~\anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\framework\func_graph.py
>   in func_graph_from_py_func(name, python_func, args, kwargs, signature,
>   func_graph, autograph, autograph_options, add_control_dependencies,
>   arg_names, op_return_value, collections, capture_by_value,
>   override_flat_arg_shapes)
>       976                                           converted_func)
>       977 
>   --> 978       func_outputs = python_func(*func_args, **func_kwargs)
>       979 
>       980       # invariant: `func_outputs` contains only Tensors, CompositeTensors,
>
> ~\anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\def_function.py
>   in wrapped_fn(*args, **kwds)
>       437         # **wrapped** allows AutoGraph to swap in a converted function. We give
>       438         # the function a weak reference to itself to avoid a reference cycle.
>   --> 439         return weak_wrapped_fn().**wrapped**(*args, **kwds)
>       440     weak_wrapped_fn = weakref.ref(wrapped_fn)
>       441
>
> ~\anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\saved_model\function_deserialization.py
>   in restored_function_body(*args, **kwargs)
>       260         .format(_pretty_format_positional(args), kwargs,
>       261                 len(saved_function.concrete_functions),
>   --> 262                 "\n\n".join(signature_descriptions)))
>       263 
>       264   concrete_function_objects = []
>
> ValueError: Could not find matching function to call loaded from the
>
> > SavedModel. Got:   Positional arguments (1 total):
> >         * Tensor("inputs:0", shape=(None, 256, 256, 3), dtype=uint8)   Keyword arguments: {}
> >
> > Expected these arguments to match one of the following 1 option(s):
> >
> > Option 1:   Positional arguments (1 total):
> >         * TensorSpec(shape=(None, 256, 256, 3), dtype=tf.float32, name='inputs')   Keyword arguments: {}

Comment: Did you check my answer below? Did it helped you or still throwing same error?

Answer (score 0):

I think the loaded model expecting a input signature (shape and dtype) different from the provided input signature. Specifically, loaded model is expecting tensorflow dtype (`tf.float32`) but you provided `float32`. Can you try to replace

```
x = x.astype('float32') # dtype of x is numpy float32 which is not what the loaded model expecting here
```

by

```
x = tf.cast(x,tf.float32) # this makes x to be of correct signature
```

Please check below what happened in each line

```
x=prepare('img.jpg')     # x is numpy array
# whenever you run a tensorflow operation on a numpy array, it becomes a tensor and vice versa
x = tf.keras.utils.normalize(x, axis=1)  # x becomes a tensor
x = x.astype('float32')  # dtype of x changed back to numpy float32
print(x.dtype)           # prints correctly float32 (notice that its not tf.float32)
prediction = model.predict([x]) # this throws an error as the underlying concrete function expects input of tf.float32 signature
```

I don't see any other issue. I suggest you to read about `concrete function` and `input signature`.